# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have used cocoapods to install the upnpx library which successfully builds. But as soon as I went to build after using one of the classes In my project I am faced with this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UPnPManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RendererView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you using the workspace file created by CocoaPods? It's called `<project-name>.xcworkspace` and should be used instead of `<project-name>.xcodeproj`

Comment: Yes I am using the workspace, turns out setting "Build active architectures only" to YES in build settings of the project fixes this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: For me, setting "Build active architectures only" to YES in build settings of the project target resolves this issue